# Help with equivalence stated in average reward setting RL in Sutton's book

Tags: mathematical-statistics, reinforcement-learning

In page 202 of [the latest draft of Richard S. Sutton's RL book](http://incompleteideas.net/book/bookdraft2017nov5.pdf), the average-reward setting for RL is introduced, and there the author states the equivalence:

$$\lim_{h\to \infty} \frac{1}{h} \sum_{t=1}^h \mathbb E[R_t | A_{0:t-1}\sim \pi] = \lim_{t\to\infty} \mathbb E[R_t| A_{0:t-1}\sim \pi]~. $$

Why is this true? How can I prove this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write $\frac{1}{h} \sum\limits_{t=1}^{h} E[\ldots]$ as $E [E[\ldots]]$. Then the proof is trivial.

Of course you have to use the assumption that the reward is well bounded or dominated by some function. In this case I think its easier to argue with a bound.

Comment: In order to write the summation as an integral, I assume you're forced to interpret the term $\frac{1}{h}$ as a probability, correct? If that's the case, isn't that a uniform distribution over the positive integers ([which can't exist](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/14777/why-isnt-there-a-uniform-probability-distribution-over-the-positive-real-number))?

Comment: Ah, now I noticed your equation doesn't have a limit in it. So it is a uniform distribution over only a finite number of integers.

Comment: And I also noticed that the link I posted relates to uniform distribution over reals, not integers.